# How to create a file using goorm terminal

Tags: terminal, ide, containers

Hi i am not able to figure out what is the command for creating a file from terminal in **Goorm ide** . Just to make clear i want to create new file only from terminal not by gui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like in other Linux terminals, you can type `touch filename` to create a file via [goormIDE](https://ide.goorm.io) terminal.

FYI:

- Type `mkdir foldername` to create a directory
- Type `goorm filename` to open a file in [goormIDE](https://ide.goorm.io) editor

Comment: and for opening i fgured out its--> touch filename

Answer (score 0):

goormide is ubuntu os.
so you can create files by typing common linux commands like `touch data.json`